# Optimizing for update only files of size 4-20kb on restricted NVMe AWS disks (Low bandwidth, low latency)

Tags: performance, go, io, filesystems

Working on a problem statement where we can't use a DB, instead, we have to implement our own.

Problem statement:-

- A request is made to the server with blob (4KB avg, 20KB max) with a `UUID` and store the blob on disk, sounds perfect use-case for key-pair [blobfs](https://spdk.io/doc/blobfs.html), but the catch is, a request from the same `UUID` will be made again and we'll have to replace the previously written data with a new one, i.e at any point of time we're only concerned with the latest blob.
- Request from the same `UUID` will be made every 10 seconds.
- `SIGKILL` could be made to the server to check the integrity of files. It's okay to lose data of requests made in the last 3 seconds. However, we'd want to make this time as low as possible.
- Number of writes is way more than the number of reads
- We want to know the maximum number of `UUID`s we can support on the given infrastructure.

Infrastructure:-

- We have a `c6gd.large` AWS instance which comes with 4GB RAM, 2 CPUs, 120GB NVMe. But the problem with NVMe is that the bandwidth is restricted by AWS ([source](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=865656)), however, we do get low latency (within 150 microseconds).

As shown below, we get more bandwidth while storing in bs of 5kb than 1GB. Also creating a new file is faster than overwriting an existing one.

[image: disk benchmark]

What I've tried so far:-

- Because of the above benchmarks, for each request, I create/update a file with each `UUID` and write the blob to it.
- I've tried both `xfs` and `ext4` filesystem and `ext4` performs a bit better and is giving around 8.5k Requests/Second for a 2 hour test. Which means we can support 85k probes as each probe will send request only once every 10 seconds.
- I've tested using `wrk` and noticed that CPU usage on average is around 70-80% and RAM usage is around 3GB (out of 4GB)
- I've mounted the disk with `ext4` with `rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime,journal_async_commit,nobarrier` these mount options.
- NOTE: I've benchmarked the http server alone and it's supporting 100k Req/sec, hence it won't be a bottleneck.
- I've used golang for it and this is how I'm writing to file.

[image: golang-write-to-file]

---

I've read about RocksDB architecture, and LSM trees looks promising however I'm of the opinion that compaction process won't give us a huge benefit given that badwidth is just around 100MBps. Am I wrong to think that?

Another question that's in mind is when there are say 1000 writes in a batch to go on disk, I'm assuming that the fs (ext4) journaling will sort these operations. Is this assumpting correct? If not is there a way to enforce this? Also can I batch these write requests to be processed **every** say 100ms?

Are there any other ideas which I can try?

Comment: Please, don't use screenshots for code and error messages. It is hard to reproduce and search engines have problems finding data that are inserted as images as well.

Comment: @Ruli so rather just paste them as code blocks? I'll follow that from now on. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is way better for everyone, you can use code formatting in editor, there are hints and help you can follow.

Answer (score 0):

### ideas

- buffer requests(go channel, unix datagram socket, redis, ...)
- bulk upsert every 100ms

### tried

- badger db & go channel
- rocks db  & unix datagram socket
- sqlite3   & unix datagram socket

### not tried

- RabbitMQ
- Kafka
- Nats
- PostgreSQL
- Redis

| front | communication | db | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| net/http(go) | go channel | badger(go) | killed(OOM) |
| net/http(go) | unix datagram socket | rocksdb(rust) | many timeouts |
| net/http(go) | unix datagram socket | sqlite3(rust) | 18,000 rps |

### benchmark result

latency distribution(ms) and requests per second

| 50% | 75% | 90% | 99% | rps | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.6 | 0.7 | 1.2 | 9.9 | 176k | 1. create files(direct) |
| 2.4 | 4.5 | 7.1 | 14 | 54k | 2. create files(indirect) |
| 6.9 | 13 | 19 | 71 | 18k | 3. sqlite3 |
| 10 | 18 | 24 | 46 | 13k | 4. upsert files(dirty) |
| 339 | 350 | 667 | 1320 | 0.4k | 5. upsret files(fdatasync) |

- connections: 128
- threads: 128
- duration: 60 seconds

###### 1. create files(direct)

- wrk -> GET request
- GET request -> actix web server
- create empty files

###### 2. create files(indirect)

- wrk -> GET request
- GET request -> net/http server
- data(4k) -> unix datagram socket
- unix datagram socket -> create empty files

###### 3. sqlite3

- wrk -> GET request
- GET request -> net/http server
- data(4k) -> unix datagram socket
- unix datagram socket -> channel(buffer=128)
- channel -> sqlite3(bulk upserts, every 100 ms)

###### 4. upsert files(dirty)

- wrk -> GET request
- GET request -> net/http server
- data(4k) -> unix datagram socket
- unix datagram socket -> ext4(without fdatasync)

###### 5. upsret files(fdatasync)

- wrk -> GET request
- GET request -> net/http server
- data(4k) -> unix datagram socket
- unix datagram socket -> ext4(temp file)
- fdatasync
- rename

### local pc info

#### storage

cat /etc/fstab

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults        0 1
```

#### cpuinfo

fgrep 'model name' /proc/cpuinfo|cat -n

```
     1  model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
     2  model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
     3  model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
     4  model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
     5  model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
     6  model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
     7  model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
     8  model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
     9  model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
    10  model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
    11  model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
    12  model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
```

#### dd

```
% dd if=/dev/zero of=./zeros.dat bs=4096 count=262144
262144+0 records in
262144+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 2.67881 s, 401 MB/s

% dd if=/dev/zero of=./zeros.dat bs=4096 count=262144 conv=fdatasync
262144+0 records in
262144+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 1.02852 s, 1.0 GB/s

% dd if=/dev/zero of=./zeros.dat bs=4096 count=262144 conv=fsync
262144+0 records in
262144+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 0.875749 s, 1.2 GB/s
```